# How can I access to network camera without changing IP?

Tags: networking, ip-camera

[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIVtI.png)

I can't embed image yet because I don't have 10 reputations so I posted link instead.

If I change IP to 192.168.1.x, I can access to camera but not to the Internet.

If I keep IP to 10.240.33.168, I can access to the Internet but not to camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by requesting IP address for the camera.

Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 0):

Is 10.240.33.168 your public ip address?
You shouldn't post that here.
Your router gives you a private ip address the same way that it gives your camera a private ip address.
I didn't quite get your question. Are you trying to connect your pc to your camera? Can't you just use the private ip address you already have?

Comment: 10.240.33.168 is not public.

Comment: I can't connect camera to my PC directly because there is another computer need to access camera.

Due to company policy, only Windows machine can have custom IP address.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access both IP camera and internet, you could configure your network adapter to use 2 network addresses.

In adapter settings, in Windows, where you define you define your static IP address, click the "advanced" button. you will be able to configure a second IP address for the same network adapter.

[image: add second network address]

Comment: I have solved this problem by requesting IP address for the camera.

Thank you for answering.